# Docker COPY and effect on permissions?

Tags: permissions, puppet

I'm modifying an [existing docker image](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker/blob/master/puppetserver/Dockerfile) which was originally as follows:

```
FROM puppet/puppetserver-standalone:2.7.2

ENV PUPPETDB_TERMINUS_VERSION="4.3.0"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y puppetdb-termini="$PUPPETDB_TERMINUS_VERSION"-1puppetlabs1 && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN puppet config set storeconfigs_backend puppetdb --section main && \
    puppet config set storeconfigs true --section main && \
    puppet config set reports puppetdb --section main

COPY puppetdb.conf /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/

COPY Dockerfile /
```

There is already a command copying to `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/` I'm now an additional script to the same folder by adding a second `COPY` as follows:

```
COPY node.sh /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/
```

This change compiles but when I use the image in a docker-compose project everything breaks. It seems to be related to a permission issue:

> puppet              | Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException:
>   (RuntimeError) Got 8 failure(s) while initializing:
>   File[/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/state]: change from
>   absent to directory failed: Could not set 'directory' on ensure:
>   Permission denied - /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/state;
>   File[/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/lib]: change from absent
>   to directory failed: Could not set 'directory' on ensure: Permission
>   denied - /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/lib;
>   File[/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/preview]: change from
>   absent to directory failed: Could not set 'directory' on ensure:
>   Permission denied - /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/preview;
>   File[/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/bucket]: change from
>   absent to directory failed: Could not set 'directory' on ensure:
>   Permission denied - /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/bucket;
>   File[/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/yaml]: change from
>   absent to directory failed: Could not set 'directory' on ensure:
>   Permission denied - /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/yaml;
>   File[/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/server_data]: change
>   from absent to directory failed: Could not set 'directory' on ensure:
>   Permission denied -
>   /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/server_data;
>   File[/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/reports]: change from
>   absent to directory failed: Could not set 'directory' on ensure:
>   Permission denied - /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/reports;
>   File[/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/facts.d]: change from
>   absent to directory failed: Could not set 'directory' on ensure:
>   Permission denied - /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/facts.d

I'm really puzzled because there was already a `.conf` file being copied to the same folder before I added my modification. Does anyone have an idea on how this change may have affected permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [page on DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/puppet/puppetserver/) the image code should be identical to the [github code](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker/blob/master/puppetserver/Dockerfile).

I found that importing the image directly in a second docker image instead of modifying the original seemed to work:

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM puppet/puppetserver

COPY node.sh /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/
```